# Foreign key accept null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I make the foreign key of a table **"PRODUCT"** accept null values?

I require that at the time of filling the **PRODUCT** form you can save the information without having to select the bank. I generate the form PRODUCT(Controller) with **entity framework**

The foreign key del model Product  ->  **"public  int EntidadID { get; set; }"**

I have two related models.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string NumContrato { get; set; }

    public float TasaReal { get; set; }

    public decimal Capital { get; set; }

    public DateTime FechaValor { get; set; }

    public DateTime FechaVencimiento { get; set; }

    public int Plazo { get; set; }

    public  int BankID { get; set; }

    public virtual CATbank CATbank { get; set; }

}

public class CATbank
{

    [Key]
    public int BankID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is BankID your foreign key?

If so, in the Product class try changing

`public int BankID { get; set; }`

to

`public int? BankID { get; set; }`

and in your database table make sure that the field is nullable.